# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on PROCEDURE OR FUNCTION migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have 2 machines. One with php 5.6 and the other with php 7.

The one with php 5.6 has:

`[root@bd-mg ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

The other with php 7 has:

`[root@XXX]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.59-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

When I run the migrations on the machine with php 5.6, I have no problems. All the tables, views, procedures and functions are created. But in the other machine, when I run `php artisan migrate` I have these errors:

```
[root@XXX]# php artisan migrate

In Connection.php line 647:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `genera_pr
  oyeccion_demanda`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION da' at line 1 (SQL: REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `genera_proyeccion_demanda`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION date) RETURNS double
  BEGIN
  END
  )


In PDOConnection.php line 62:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `genera_pr
  oyeccion_demanda`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION da' at line 1


In PDOConnection.php line 60:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `genera_proyeccion_demanda`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION da' at line 1
```

My functions or procedures has more code of course, but I was trying to minimize the code to discard that was a syntax problem, but I don't get, in my other machine works but not here:
[image]

This error occurs even with the procedures or functions almost empty. Any ideas? The database user is root, and I'm running php artisan as root also.

Comment: From the error it seems the more recent PHP PDO does not like the REPLACE sql command in your migration (2018_05_24_202139_create_genera_proyeccion_demanda_function)

Comment: YES!! That is! I remove it and it works. Thanks! Put an answer and I'll pick it as correct.

Comment: The only problem now is if the table exist, I'll get another error and the execution of the rest of the migrations will stop. But thanks, that's another story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, the console errors from the `php artisan migrate` command are informing you that the SQL REPLACE syntax is not accepted.

It seems like this stems from the newer PDO in php7. The version shipped with php5.6 apparently accepted the syntax but the version in php7 does not.

The offending syntax is in the migration `2018_05_24_202139_create_genera_proyeccion_demanda_function`

If you need to confirm if a table exists, you can use the Schema::hasTable() method, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#tables